# Partial derivative in the Minimization problem (Ritz) formulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, numerical-methods, partial-derivative

Let $F(u)=\int L = \int_0^1 (\frac{1}{2}(u')^2 - qu)dx$ (*) 
Then, using the approximation $u_h = \sum_j u_j\varphi_j(x) \ \forall u_h \in \mathcal{V}_h$, where $\mathcal{V}_h$ is the space of test functions with the $span\{\varphi_1,\dots\varphi_n\}$ we have: 
(*) = $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}(\sum_j u_j\varphi_j')^2-q\sum_j u_j\varphi_j(x) \ dx$ 
We want to minimize $F(u)$ and therefore calculate $\frac{\partial{F(u)}}{\partial u_i}$ 
We suppose that we can move derivation sign under the integral because $L$ is sufficiently continuous and integrable.

Then I suppose we have (1): $\frac{\partial \frac{1}{2}(\sum_j u_j\varphi_j')^2}{\partial u_i}=\sum_j (u_j\varphi_j'+u_j'\varphi_j)(u_j\frac{\partial \varphi_j'}{\partial u_i}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial u_i}\varphi_j')=\sum_j u_j^2\varphi_j'\varphi_i'$

Does (1) correct?

EDITED (1):

$\frac{\partial \frac{1}{2}(\sum_j u_j\varphi_j')^2}{\partial u_i}=\sum_j (u_j\varphi_j')(\frac{\partial (u_j\varphi_j')}{\partial u_i})=\sum_j u_j\varphi_j'\varphi_i'$

I know that $\frac{\partial(u_j \varphi_j')}{\partial u_i}=\varphi_i'$, but could you please explain **why is it so**? Why the index is changed?

I tried to go through the limit definition but didn't get a thing.

Thank you

Comment: This is just taking the derivative with respect to the $i^{th}$ coefficient. If $$u=\sum_{j}^{n}u_{j}\varphi_{j}'=u_{1}\varphi_{1}'+\dots+u_{i}\varphi_{i}'+\dots+u_{n} \varphi_{n}'$$ where $1\le i\le n$ then $\partial u/\partial u_{i}=\varphi_{i}'$. In turn, the integral (which we'll call $I$) becomes
\begin{align}\frac{\partial I}{\partial u_{i}}&=\int_{0}^{1}\left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\left(\sum_{j}u_{j}\varphi_{j}'\right)\varphi_{i}'-q\varphi_{i}\right]dx\\&= \dots \end{align}
However, I'm pretty sure you should be differentiating the basis $\varphi_{j}$, not the coefficients $u_{j}$.

Comment: Thank you! So the expression (1) in my question is incorrect?
Sorry, didn't get the last line, we differentiate the functional $I$ - $\frac{\partial I}{\partial u_i}$. What do you mean by the "differentiating the basis $\varphi_j$"?

Comment: By the way, if we continue to investigate the expression which you've stated we will have the $n$ system of linear equations 

$\sum_j\varphi_i'\varphi_j'u_j=q\varphi_i$ for $i: 1\dots n$ $\implies$ $Au=b$